# How can I understand these destructors?

Tags: c++, oop, heap-memory, destructor, virtual-destructor

I'm confused about the following C++ code (run it online at http://cpp.sh/8bmp).  It combines several concepts I'm learning about in a course.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        A() {cout << "A ctor" << endl;}
        virtual ~A() {cout << "A dtor" << endl;}
};

class B: public A {
    public:
        B() {cout << "B ctor" << endl;}
        ~B() {cout << "B dtor" << endl;}
        void foo(){cout << "foo" << endl;}
};

int main(){
    B *b = new B[1];
    b->~B();
    b->foo();
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A ctor
B ctor
B dtor
A dtor
foo
A dtor
```

Here's what I don't understand:

1. Why can I call `foo` after calling the destructor?
2. Why can I call `delete` after calling the destructor?
3. If I comment out `delete b;` will this code leak memory?
4. The destructor for `A` is virtual.  I thought virtual functions overloaded in subclasses wouldn't get called.  Why does `~A()` get called then?
5. If I comment out `b->~B();` then the line `B dtor` is printed after `foo`. Why?
6. If I repeat the line `b->~B();` twice, then the output is: `B dtor\nA dtor\nA dtor`.  Huh?
7. I get the same output if I switch `delete B;` with `delete[] b;`.  I think the second one is correct because `b` is created with `new[]`, but it doesn't matter because I'm only pushing one instance of `B` to the heap.  Is that correct?

I'm sorry for asking so many questions, but this is pretty confusing to me.  If my individual questions are misguided, then tell me what I need to know to understand when each destructor will run.

Comment: `b->~B();`  You really shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: So many undefined behaviors :/ ...

Comment: "It combines several concepts I'm learning about in a course." It must not be a very good course if they didn't teach you basic stuff like "don't access objects you destroyed".

Answer (score 6):

"Undefined behaviour" (UB for short) is where the compiler is allowed to do anything - this commonly means somewhere between "crash", "give incorrect result" and "do what you'd expect anyway". Your `b->foo()` is definitely undefined, since it happens after your `b->~B()` call,

Since your `foo` function doesn't actually USE anything that gets destroyed by the destructor, the call to `foo` "works", because there is nothing being used that has been destroyed. [This is by no means guaranteed - it JUST HAPPENS to work, a bit like sometimes it's fine to cross a road without looking, at other times it's not. Depending on what road it is, it may be a really bad idea, or might work most of the time - but there is a reason people say "look left, look right, look left, then cross if it's safe" (or something like that)]

Calling `delete` on an object that has been destroyed is also UB, so again, it's pure luck that it "works" (in the sense of "doesn't cause your program to crash").

Also mixing `delete` with `new []` or vice versa is UB - again, the compiler [and it's related runtime] may do the right or the wrong thing, depending on circumstances and conditions.

**Do Not** rely on undefined behaviour in your program [1]. It is bound to come back and bite you. C and C++ have quite a few UB-cases, and it's good to understand at least the most common cases, such as "use after destruction", "use after free" and such, and be on the lookout for such cases - and avoid it at all costs!

Comment: Thanks for the really quick answer! The only thing I don't understand is the 4th list item about why the overloaded virtual destructor gets called (why does ~A() run) edit: or is this also caused by the UB

Comment: Because destructors are always "chained" - in other words, all the destructors of the classes a class is derived from will get called when the "final" class's destructor is called. So the code inside `~B()` will have a call to `~A()` in it. The `delete` function doesn't know all the class hierarchy that you have, it will just call the destructor of the actual object that was created [which in your case is `virtual`]

Comment: haha "a bit like sometimes it's fine to cross a road without looking, at other times it's not"... what a great analogy :)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why can I call `foo` after calling the destructor?

C++ doesn't stop you from shooting yourself in the foot. Just because you can do it (and the code doesn't immediately crash) doesn't mean it's legal or well defined.

> 2. Why can I call `delete` after calling the destructor?

Same as answer #1.

> 3. If I comment out `delete b;` will this code leak memory?

Yes. You **must** `delete` what you `new` (and `delete[]` what you `new[]`).

> 4. The destructor for `A` is virtual. I thought virtual functions overloaded in subclasses wouldn't get called. Why does ~A() get called then?

I think the word you want is *override*, not *overload*. Anyway, you're not overriding `~A()`. Notice that `~B()` and `~A()` have different names.

Destructors are kinda special. When the derived class's destructor is finished running, it implicitly calls the base class's destructor. Why? Because the C++ standard says that's what will happen.

A *virtual* destructor is a special destructor. I lets you polymorphically delete an object. That means you can do code like the following:

```
B *b = new B;
A *a = b;
delete a; // Legal with virtual destructors, illegal without virtual.
```

If `A` did not have a virtual destructor in the code above, it would not call `~B()`, which would be undefined behavior. With a virtual destructor, the compiler will correctly call `~B()` when `delete a;` is run, even though `a` is an `A*` and not a `B*`.

> 5. If I comment out `b->~B();` then the line `B dtor` is printed after `foo`. Why?

Because it's run after `foo()`. `delete b;` implicitly calls `b`'s destructor, which is after `foo()` has already run.

> 6. If I repeat the line `b->~B();` twice, then the output is: `B dtor\nA dtor\nA dtor`. Huh?

It's undefined behavior. So anything can happen, really. Yeah, that's weird output. Undefined behavior is weird.

> 7. I get the same output if I switch `delete B;` with `delete[] b;`. I think the second one is correct because `b` is created with `new[]`, but it doesn't matter because I'm only pushing one instance of `B` to the heap. Is that correct?

It matters what you call. `delete` and `delete[]` are not the same thing. You can't call one in place of the other. You **must** call `delete` only on memory that's been allocated with `new`, and `delete[]` with memory that's been allocated with `new[]`. You **cannot** mix and match as you want. Doing so is undefined behavior.

You should be using `delete[]` here, in this code, because you used `new[]`.

Comment: Thank you! This answered all of my questions

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Calling a method on a destroyed object is "Undefined Behaviour". Meaning that the standard does not specify what should happen. The idea behind UB is that they are supposed to be bugs in the application logic, but for performance reason, we do not force the compiler to do something special about it, as that would degrade performance for when we do things correctly.

In this case, because the foo() method does not depends on anything in the memory pointed by `b`, it will work as expected. Just because the compiler does not do any test on it.

Q2: This is also "Undefined Behaviour". And you can see already some bizarre things are happening. First, the B destructor is not called, just the A destructor. What is happening is that when you called previously `b->~B()`, the B destructor was called, then the vtable of the object was changed to a A vtable (meaning the object runtime type became A) and then the A destructor was called. When you called `delete b`, the runtime called the virtual destructor of the object which was A. Like said previously, this is "Undefined Beheviour". The compiler chhose to generate code that works that way when calling `delete b`, but it could have generated different code and still be right.

If fact, something worse has probably been done after calling the A destructor because of another bug in your code: you use `delete` instead of `delete[]`. C++ rules states that arrays allocated with `operator new[]` must be freed using `operator delete[]` and that using `operator delete` is "Undefined behaviour". In fact, in most implementation I know, doing that will work the first time, but has a good chance of corrupting the memory management data, so that a future call to `new` or `delete`, even valid, may crash or cause memory leak.

Q3: There will be a memory leak if you remove the call. You will probably have memory corruption  if you keep the call. Memory leak will be avoided if you use `delete[] b` instead. There is still undefined behaviour because a destrutor will be called on the already destroyed object, but because these destructors do nothing, they will not likely do any more damage to your program

Q4: This is the rule with all destructors, not just virtual destructors: they will destroy the member objects then the base objects at the end of the code.

Q5: So when the compiler generates the code for the B destructor, it adds at the end a call to the A destructor. But there is a rule: at this time, `this` is not a B object anymore and during the call to any virtual method in the A destructor, A methods must be called, not B methods, even if virtual. So before calling the A destructor, the B destructor will "downgrade" the dynamic type of the object from B to A (in practice, that means setting the vtable of the object to the A vtable). As the goal of the compiler is to generate efficient code, it does not have to change the vtable at the end of the A destructor. Remember: any method call on the object after the destructor is called is "Undefined Behaviour". Priority is performance, not bug detection.

Q6: same answer as Q5, and I also talked about is in Q2

Q7: It matters. A lot. delete[] needs to know the number of objects created so it can call the destrutors for all the objects in the array. Often implementations of new[] will actually allocate a `size_t` element to store the number of objects in the array before the elements of the array. So the returned pointer is not the start of the allocated bloc, but the location after the size (4 bytes on 32 bits system, 8 bytes on 64 bits system). So first `new B[1]` will allocate 4 or 8 bytes more that `new B` and second delete[] will need to decrement the pointer by 4 or 8 bytes before deallocating it. So `delete b` and `delete[] b` are VERY different.

Note: compilers are not mandated to implement `new[]` and `delete[]` that way. And some implementations offer version of the runtime library that do more checkings so that bugs are easier to detect. However, for the best performance, `delete[]` MUST be called if `new[]` is used. And if you make the mistake to call `delete` on a pointer allocated by `new[]`, most of the time, it will not crash or fail the first time you do it. It will likely crash or fail later in a perfectly legal `new`, `new[]`, `delete` or `delete[]` operation. Which often means a lot of head scratching wondering why a perfectly correct operation is failing. This is the true meaning of "Undefined Behaviour"